# Unable to create users through CLI

Tags: airflow

I have installed airflow 1.10.13 in my server and I am trying to create role based users for authentication. I tried using `airflow create_user` in CLI but the user is not created though the command says user created.

[image]

when I look at list of users `airflow list_users` this user is not available and I cannot login in the UI as well.

[image]

Further I am sure email, firstname, last name are optional arguments but it says these are required.

[image]

Would appreciate if someone could help me how to create role based users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use role-based access control you need to [enable this feature](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.13/security.html#rbac-ui-security) in `airflow.cfg`:

```
rbac = True
```

Email, firstname, and last name are required arguments, but you can specify any string for them.